# No Helvet with sections @ pdflatex

Tags: sectioning, errors, pdftex, helvetica

After hours of searching and trying, i dont know a way out - i am not able to get `helvetica` font to work with `pdflatex`. What i found out - without any sections (2 examples in here) it will work without an error.

Can anyone help me out with this? I am freaking out :((

I added the tex and my pdflatex log:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[center]{caption}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[babel,german=guillemets]{csquotes}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear-icomp,
sortlocale=de_DE,    
    natbib=true,
    url=false,
    doi=true,
    eprint=false,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}


\section{dffsa}
\section{dffsa2}

\newpage

Test


Not him old music think his found enjoy merry. Listening acuteness dependent at or an. Apartments thoroughly unsatiable terminated sex how themselves. She are ten hours wrong walls stand early. Domestic perceive on an ladyship extended received do. Why jennings our whatever his learning gay perceive. Is against no he without subject. Bed connection unreserved preference partiality not unaffected. Years merit trees so think in hoped we as. 

\end{document}
```

Log:

```
("C:\Users\deskt\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backen
d-pdfmode.def"
File: l3backend-pdfmode.def 2020-06-23 L3 backend support: PDF mode
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count390
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box47
) (testfile.aux)
\openout1 = `testfile.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+phv on input line 24
.

("C:\Users\deskt\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/psnfss\t1phv.fd"
File: t1phv.fd 2020/03/25 scalable font definitions for T1/phv.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/phv/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 11.39996pt on input line 24.

*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: pdftex
* paper: a4paper
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(56.9055pt, 483.69687pt, 56.9055pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(56.9055pt, 759.6886pt, 28.45274pt)
* \paperwidth=597.50787pt
* \paperheight=845.04684pt
* \textwidth=483.69687pt
* \textheight=759.6886pt
* \oddsidemargin=-15.36449pt
* \evensidemargin=-15.36449pt
* \topmargin=-55.23949pt
* \headheight=18.125pt
* \headsep=21.75pt
* \topskip=12.0pt
* \footskip=50.75pt
* \marginparwidth=49.79233pt
* \marginparsep=12.8401pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=10.8pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

Package caption Info: Begin \AtBeginDocument code.
Package caption Info: hyperref package is loaded.
Package caption Info: End \AtBeginDocument code.

("C:\Users\deskt\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-p
df.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count391
\scratchdimen=\dimen157
\scratchbox=\box48
\nofMPsegments=\count392
\nofMParguments=\count393
\everyMPshowfont=\toks21
\MPscratchCnt=\count394
\MPscratchDim=\dimen158
\MPnumerator=\count395
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count396
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks22
)
("C:\Users\deskt\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epsto
pdf-base.sty"
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'ngerman'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'ngerman.lbx' found.

("C:\Users\deskt\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/biblatex/lbx\ngerm
an.lbx"
File: ngerman.lbx 2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'german'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'german.lbx' found.

("C:\Users\deskt\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/biblatex/lbx\germa
n.lbx"
File: german.lbx 2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'german'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'german.lbx' found.

("C:\Users\deskt\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/biblatex/lbx\germa
n.lbx"
File: german.lbx 2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
))
Package biblatex Info: Input encoding 'utf8' detected.
Package biblatex Info: Automatic encoding selection.
(biblatex)             Assuming data encoding 'utf8'.
\openout3 = `testfile.bcf'.

Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliographic data...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'testfile.bbl' found.
 (testfile.bbl)
Package biblatex Info: Reference section=0 on input line 24.
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=0 on input line 24.
\AtBeginShipoutBox=\box49
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 24.

("C:\Users\deskt\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\nameref.s
ty"
Package: nameref 2019/09/16 v2.46 Cross-referencing by name of section

("C:\Users\deskt\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/refcount\refcount.
sty"
Package: refcount 2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
)
("C:\Users\deskt\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/gettitlestring\g
ettitlestring.sty"
Package: gettitlestring 2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count397
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 24.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 24.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 24.
 (testfile.out) (testfile.out)
\@outlinefile=\write4
\openout4 = `testfile.out'.

Class scrartcl Info: loading recommended package `bookmark'.
(scrartcl)           Using `bookmark' together with `hyperref' is recommended,
(scrartcl)           because of handling of possible bookmark level gaps.
(scrartcl)           You can avoid loading `bookmark' with KOMA-Script option
(scrartcl)           `bookmarkpackage=false' before \begin{document} and
(scrartcl)           you can avoid this message adding:
(scrartcl)             \usepackage{bookmark}
(scrartcl)           before \begin{document} on input line 24.

("C:\Users\deskt\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/bookmark\bookmark.
sty"
Package: bookmark 2019/12/03 v1.28 PDF bookmarks (HO)

("C:\Users\deskt\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/bookmark\bkm-pdfte
x.def"
File: bkm-pdftex.def 2019/12/03 v1.28 bookmark driver for pdfTeX (HO)
Package auxhook Info: \AddLineBeginMainAux comes a little late,
(auxhook)             because the main .aux file is already opened on input lin
e 168.
\BKM@id=\count398
))
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/phv/b/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 11.39996pt on input line 27.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/phv/b/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 16.41594pt on input line 27.
 [1
```

Comment: this is not the pdflatex.log, it is a miktex specific log. Show the log of your document. And say what you mean by "it doesn't work".

Comment: okay i did not know that - i found the correct log and added it to my topic.
Doesnt work means its not generating any valid pdf file. I use Texmaker and its not showing any warning except the log file you mentioned.

Comment: i just posted the last 25% of the log because its so long - i hope this will be enough

Comment: these are not the last 25% unless you killed the compilation somehow.

Comment: These are the last 25% and the last characters are [1 I checked this twice because i thought there must be more. You have an Idea whats going on?

Comment: compile on a command line to get a better error message.

Comment: not sure about that - but pdflatex from cmd shows: ("C:\Users\deskt\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/bookmark\bkm-pdfte
x.def")) [1
Sorry, but pdflatex did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\deskt\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\pdflatex.log

Comment: Hm. What happens if you call the task "refresh font map files" in the menu of the miktex console (user mode)? Does it work then?

Comment: Does not work after refresh font map files - same error @ ("C:\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/bookmark\bkm-pdftex.def")) [1

Comment: Does it compile if you remove the helvet package?

Comment: yes - there are two options to make it working: remove helvet or remove the two sections (\section{dffsa} and \section{dffsa2}) both produce a pdf and no errors

Comment: hm the section should simply use a bold font. What happens if you replace them with \textbf{abc}. Does it break then too?

Comment: Yes it breaks at the same line ending with [1. If i can come back to the miktex log, i noticed the messages containing... still open - tex file name with various endings only appears If the compiling fails. Maybe this can Help?

Comment: Do you have on-the-fly installation enabled? If yes can you deactivate it and then try again on a command line? Perhaps it gives a better error message.

Comment: Does replacing `helvet` with `tgheros` work?

Comment: i had on the fly enabled - i reinstalled miktex and turned it off - compiling by cmd line with lot of manual installations - same result. tgheros is working. I also tried some noob stuff - as the compiling stopped around the bookmark/pdf thing - i also added the package "bookmark" - now it stops with this msg @cmdline : ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/biblatex/lbx\german.lbx")) No file testfile.bbl. [1 - and this in last code lines: 
No file testfile.bbl.
Package biblatex Info: Reference section=0 on input line 24.
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=0 on input line 24.
[1

Comment: Question: Are you able to compile the file in my initial post?

Comment: you are perhaps affected by this bug: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/568

Comment: looks like - i used a complete different computer now with same results.

Comment: Seems like the fix is not working for me. Copied to bin/x64 (replaced the exe) and ran the command - but same Error happened after. Ist there a way to validate this fix If i die IT right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix from: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/568
finally solved the Problem - will be fixed with next Version