# Why is pdflatex throwing this error related to C4P.h?

Tags: pdftex

I'm trying to compile some tex documents on a fresh installation of MiKTex and TeXstudio on a new computer. My files compile without issue on my other computers. But when I try to compile them here they produce a mysterious error. The console simply states

> Sorry, but pdflatex.exe did not succeed. The log file hopefully
> contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
> C:\Users\ajaym\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\pdflatex.log

And when I consult the log file I find the excerpt below. I'm not particularly competent in the inner workings of pdflatex. It appears the error is being generated in "Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\include\miktex/C4P/C4P.h:255" but the message itself isn't very helpful in resolving the issue.

I have to assume the problem is with my system or my MiKTex install (as I said, the files compile without issue on my other computer). But I've tried reinstalling both MiKTex and TeXstudio (private installs rather than admin installs, as recommended by the installer). I'm running on an up-to-date version of Windows 10 (as is the computer that compiles the file successfully). To be honest I have no idea where to start. All of my Google searches have turned up nothing.

Thanks for any help you can offer--
Ajay Shenoy

```
2020-06-29 13:06:02,720-0700 INFO  pdflatex - this process (18684) started by 'texstudio' with command line: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode landtenure20200619.tex
2020-06-29 13:06:02,727-0700 INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands
2020-06-29 13:06:02,727-0700 INFO  pdflatex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2020-06-29 13:06:03,319-0700 FATAL pdflatex.core - Read operation failed.
2020-06-29 13:06:03,319-0700 FATAL pdflatex.core - Data: path="", read="0", n="1"
2020-06-29 13:06:03,319-0700 FATAL pdflatex.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\include\miktex/C4P/C4P.h:255
2020-06-29 13:06:03,320-0700 FATAL pdflatex - Read operation failed.
2020-06-29 13:06:03,320-0700 FATAL pdflatex - Info: path="", read="0", n="1"
2020-06-29 13:06:03,320-0700 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\include\miktex/C4P/C4P.h
2020-06-29 13:06:03,320-0700 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 255
2020-06-29 13:06:03,320-0700 INFO  pdflatex - this process (18684) finishes with exit code 1
2020-06-29 13:06:03,320-0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: landtenure20200619.tex
2020-06-29 13:06:03,320-0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: landtenure20200619.pdf
2020-06-29 13:06:03,320-0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: landtenure20200619.out
2020-06-29 13:06:03,320-0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: landtenure20200619.log
2020-06-29 13:06:03,320-0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: C:\Users\ajaym\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\fonts/vf/adobe/utopia\putr8c.vf
2020-06-29 13:06:03,320-0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: landtenure20200619.aux
2020-06-29 13:06:03,724-0700 INFO  pdflatex - this process (12796) started by 'texstudio' with command line: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode landtenure20200619.tex
2020-06-29 13:06:03,732-0700 INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands
2020-06-29 13:06:03,732-0700 INFO  pdflatex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2020-06-29 13:06:04,309-0700 FATAL pdflatex.core - Read operation failed.
2020-06-29 13:06:04,309-0700 FATAL pdflatex.core - Data: path="", read="0", n="1"
2020-06-29 13:06:04,309-0700 FATAL pdflatex.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\include\miktex/C4P/C4P.h:255
2020-06-29 13:06:04,309-0700 FATAL pdflatex - Read operation failed.
2020-06-29 13:06:04,309-0700 FATAL pdflatex - Info: path="", read="0", n="1"
2020-06-29 13:06:04,309-0700 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\include\miktex/C4P/C4P.h
2020-06-29 13:06:04,309-0700 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 255
2020-06-29 13:06:04,309-0700 INFO  pdflatex - this process (12796) finishes with exit code 1
2020-06-29 13:06:04,310-0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: landtenure20200619.tex
2020-06-29 13:06:04,310-0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: landtenure20200619.log
2020-06-29 13:06:04,310-0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: landtenure20200619.pdf
2020-06-29 13:06:04,310-0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: C:\Users\ajaym\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\fonts/vf/adobe/utopia\putr8c.vf
2020-06-29 13:06:04,310-0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: landtenure20200619.out
2020-06-29 13:06:04,310-0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: landtenure20200619.aux
2020-06-29 13:06:04,506-0700 INFO  pdflatex - this process (18964) started by 'texstudio' with command line: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode landtenure20200619.tex
2020-06-29 13:06:04,513-0700 INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands
2020-06-29 13:06:04,513-0700 INFO  pdflatex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2020-06-29 13:06:05,108-0700 FATAL pdflatex.core - Read operation failed.
2020-06-29 13:06:05,108-0700 FATAL pdflatex.core - Data: path="", read="0", n="1"
2020-06-29 13:06:05,108-0700 FATAL pdflatex.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\include\miktex/C4P/C4P.h:255
2020-06-29 13:06:05,108-0700 FATAL pdflatex - Read operation failed.
2020-06-29 13:06:05,108-0700 FATAL pdflatex - Info: path="", read="0", n="1"
2020-06-29 13:06:05,108-0700 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\include\miktex/C4P/C4P.h
2020-06-29 13:06:05,108-0700 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 255
2020-06-29 13:06:05,108-0700 INFO  pdflatex - this process (18964) finishes with exit code 1
2020-06-29 13:06:05,109-0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: landtenure20200619.tex
2020-06-29 13:06:05,109-0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: landtenure20200619.log
2020-06-29 13:06:05,109-0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: C:\Users\ajaym\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\fonts/vf/adobe/utopia\putr8c.vf
2020-06-29 13:06:05,109-0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: landtenure20200619.pdf
2020-06-29 13:06:05,109-0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: landtenure20200619.out
2020-06-29 13:06:05,109-0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: landtenure20200619.aux
```

Comment: It seems very much like https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/551476/4427

Answer (score 0):

Looks like just a few hours ago, the answer was posted here: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/568#issuecomment-651122378

It sounds like the problem will also be resolved in a future update.

Ajay